# How to get the second property type from an array of objects?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have an object mapping other objects containing `id` and `name`.

I need to get the `name` type from its `id`.

My attempt was:

```
const obj = {
    foo: { id: 1, name: 'one' },
    bar: { id: 2, name: 'two', },
    baz: { id: 3, name: 'three' },
} as const

type Obj = typeof obj;
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type Ids = ValueOf<Obj>['id'];

type GetName<T extends Ids> = (ValueOf<Obj> & { id: T })['name']

type Foo = GetName<1>
```

But `Foo` is `"one" | "two" | "three"`, while I expected to be `"one"`.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)-ing the members instead of intersecting them with `{ id: T }`:

```
type GetName<T extends Ids> = Extract<ValueOf<Obj>, { id: T }>['name']
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WPzleN)